# Why am I getting an object required error on my array variant?

Tags: excel, vba

I pass data into an array based on when column value <> column value. The array is formed fine, but when its about to move the array to a template, it gives me an object required error. This is brand new and was not erroring out before, what could fix this?

Getting error on this line:

```
Dest.Offset(j,a) = Data(i,k)
```

Rest of Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Data, Last
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
    Dim Dest As Range
    Dim BASEPATH As String
    Dim template As String

    template = "M:\.xlsx"
    BASEPATH = "M:\"

    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=template)
    Set Dest = Wb.Sheets("").Range("A3")
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Data = .Range("BQ3", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Wb.Activate
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        If Data(i, 10) <> Last Then
            If i > 1 Then
                Dest.Select
                Wb.SaveCopyAs BASEPATH & _
                ValidFileName(Last & "_YE_Planning_File.xlsx")
            End If
            With Wb.Sheets("")
                .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
            End With
            Last = Data(i, 10)
            j = 0
        End If
        a = 0
        For k = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
          Dest.Offset(j, a) = Data(i, k)
          a = a + 1
        Next
        j = j + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dest` gets deleted.

```
Set Dest = Wb.Sheets("Pay for Performance Detail").Range("A3")
...

With Wb.Sheets("Pay for Performance Detail")
    .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete  <~ this includes A3, so `Dest` is deleted
End With
```

Move the `Set Dest` to *after* you do the deletion.

Better yet, don't `Delete` within a loop? (or maybe just `ClearContents`, as apparently you already had previously)

Comment: you're the best, Ben. I had `clearcontents` there, and must've switched it up. Doy!